# How to check admin user is login or not by externally php script

Tags: magento-1.9, php, adminhtml, programmatically

I am working on externally php + magento script.My requirement write a php code from which i get all online admin users.

> Example:
>
> Admin1 - Login  - Action
>   Admin2 - Login - Action

And so on....

How can i achieve this by php script.I know to load magento app file in externally php file. Here action is logout script with the help of which i want logout admin user from this page.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('admin');

class AR
{
    public function index()
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));

        //verify if the user is logged in to the backend
        if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()){
            echo "Admin user is login";
        }
        else{
          echo "Admin user is not login";
        }

    }

}

$obj = new AR();
$obj->index();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run Magento code from a standalone php file.

This comes in handy for creating external crons or for displaying Magento output in another package like WordPress.

First, you need to locate the `app/Mage.php` file and require it in your php file.

```
require_once ‘app/Mage.php’;
```

If your Magento installation is in a subfolder then you should include that path in the require statement.

```
require_once ‘YOUR_MAGENTO_FOLDER/app/Mage.php’;
umask(0);
Load Magento:
Mage::app(‘default’); # Note: This is “app” not “run”!
```

Now you can make calls to Magento objects

You may try this for your question

```
$userName = Mage::getModel('admin/session')->getUser()->getUsername();
```

Hope this may help You..:)